# Equivalent definitions of linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

The textbook that I use define linear transformation as

> $T$ is a linear transformation if for all $\mathbf{v}$, $\mathbf{w}\in\mathbb{R}^n$ and all $a\in\mathbb{R}$, we have
>
> - $T(\mathbf{v}+\mathbf{w})=T(\mathbf{v})+T(\mathbf{w})$
> - $T(a\mathbf{v})=aT(\mathbf{v})$

However my instructor uses the following definition and he says that the two definitions (the above one and the below one) are equivalent:

> $T$ is a linear transformation if for all $\mathbf{v}$, $\mathbf{w}\in\mathbb{R}^n$ and all $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$, we have
> $T(a\mathbf{v}+b\mathbf{w})=aT(\mathbf{v})+bT(\mathbf{w})$

I can see how the first definition implies the second but how does the second definition implies the first one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the second definition, take $a=b=1$ (and $\mathbf{v},\mathbf{w}$ arbitrary) to get:

> $T(\mathbf{v}+\mathbf{w})=T(\mathbf{v})+T(\mathbf{w})$

and take $b=0$ (and $a,\mathbf{v}$ arbitrary) to get:

> $T(a\mathbf{v})=aT(\mathbf{v})$

The second formulation combines the two parts of the first so it has the advantage that you only have to check one rule to see if a transformation is linear or not.